# Paypal api doesnt pay

Tags: php, paypal

I've a question about my Paypal rest implementation. After someone buy our product in our store they can choose paypal to pay. When they choose everything works fine, they 'll redirected to Paypal. see the amount and item details. sign in and pay. after they clicked on pay they 'll redirected to our store. but nothing happend on paypal, they clicked on pay but didn't pay at all.

code:

```
public function getPaypalPayment($pin, $total, $return, $cancel)
{
$config = $this->config;

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            $config['paypal']['client'],     // ClientID
            $config['paypal']['secret']      // ClientSecret
        )
);

$apiContext->setConfig(
      array(
        'mode' => 'live'
      )
);

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item = new \PayPal\Api\Item();
$item->setName('name')
->setCurrency('USD')
->setQuantity(1)
->setPrice($total);

$itemList = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item));

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal($total);
$amount->setCurrency('USD');

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
->setItemList($itemList)
->setDescription("description")
->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($return)
->setCancelUrl($cancel);

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
->setPayer($payer)
->setTransactions(array($transaction))
->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
    return $payment->getApprovalLink();
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    return false;
    //return $ex->getData();
}   
}
```

What did i wrong, everything in paypal is on live. i tested it on sandbox mode without any failure.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's just the first part. After paying on PayPal, the user gets sent to `$returnUrl` which you don't seem to have set. There, it executes the payment. Take a look at the last snippet [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/payments/). Are there any Exceptions?

Comment: Where is your code to execute the payment? What you have shown is just getting the approval to execute. "*Next, you can optionally show payment details to the buyer on a confirmation page or you can use the payer ID from the return URL as an input parameter to execute the payment.*"

Comment: Question: During sandbox, did you actually test full transactions using a sandbox merchant account, and sandbox buyer accounts? It seems to me you left out the actual final step to claim funds.

Comment: you should probably post this under a stack job?

Comment: @ishegg can you answer my new question please!

Comment: did you execute your payment? I can see that your payment method are PayPal, which means you are required to call Execute API to complete the payment.